# How to display measure numbers in ABCjs?

Tags: discussion, abcjs

I'd like to share my practice notes and performance preparation and use ABCjs to display notation of examples.

Is there a way for ABCjs to display measure numbers?

(ABCjs seems to ignore the `%%setbarnb` pseudo comment.)

**Follow on:**

`%%setbarnb` was implemented in [abcjs issue 237](https://github.com/paulrosen/abcjs/issues/237), and requires use of `%%barnumbers` to print the line numbers, as noted by @Your Uncle Bob below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `%%barnumbers X` measure directive, which will display bar numbers every X bars. I have no idea why `%%setbarnb` doesn't work, it is part of the specification whereas the `barnumbers` directive is indicated as "volatile". Try it out [here](https://abcjs.net/abcjs-editor.html).

Comment: To add the bar number at the beginning of each line, use `%%barnumbers 0`